# Django get_or_create fails on models.ForeignKey fails

Tags: python, django, foreign-key-relationship

Have a model with two classes

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    emp_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, db_column='company_id')

class Company(models.Model):
    company_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
```

in my views.py i have a method that receive a post request and does registers an employee using `get_or_create` like so

```
employee, created = Employee.objects.get_or_create(name=emp_name, phone_number=emp_phone_number,company_id=emp_company_id)
employee.save()
```

but `get_or_create` results in an error

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'company_id' into field. Choices are:name,phone_number,company
```

how do i save the company_id as reference key?

Comment: Have you tried `employee, created = Employee.objects.get_or_create(name=emp_name, phone_number=emp_phone_number,company=emp_company_id)`?  Yes, even with emp_company_id as an integer.  I can't guarantee this is correct but I remember it being something like that.

Comment: @AndrewGorcester, nop it didn't work got the error `ValueError: Cannot assign "u'70'": "Employee.company" must be a "Company" instance.` so I did what @kviktor suggested place an entire object company=company but then i get the error `ValueError: Cannot assign "[< Company: Company object>]": "Employee.company" must be a "Company" instance.`  ???

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
company = Company.objects.get(id=company_id)

employee, created = Employee.objects.get_or_create(name=emp_name, phone_number=emp_phone_number,company=company)
employee.save()
```